# Modifying expression with exponent to another form

Tags: algebra-precalculus

*I did a math exercice where I had to prove that an expression was equal to the expression on the left hand side, so I took my expression, transformed it, and eventually I came up with the expression that you can see on the right hand side, and after a verification on Wolfram Alpha I can see that they are equal.*

**My problem is that I don't know what should I do to prove that these two expressions are equal.**

[image]

Answer (score 6):

$3\left(\frac{2}{5}\right)^{k+1}+5=3\left( \frac{2^{k+1}}{5^{k+1}}\right)+5=3\left( \frac{2^{k}\times2^1}{5^{k}\times5^1}\right)+5=\left( \frac{\color{red}3\times2^{k}\times \color{red}{2^1}}{5^{k}\times5^1}\right)+5=\left( \frac{\color{red}6\times2^{k}}{5^{k}\times5^1}\right)+5$

Comment: Thanks a lot ! But isn't it too complex for high school ? Maybe have I have transformed my first expression ((2/5) * (3(2/5)^k + 5) + 3) into something too complicated ?!

Comment: @TrevörAnneDenise, why you have written "+3" in the end? also, if you take out $\frac{2}{5}$, you should not multiply it with $5$, the way you have arranged brackets is wrong for this problem, it should be $(\frac{2}{5}\times 3 \times (\frac{2}{5})^k)+5$

Comment: I wrote it because I had a sequence with $U_{0} = 8$ and $U_{n+1} = 3(2/5)^{n} + 5$ ; I had to prove that $U_{n} = 3(2/5)^{n} + 5$, so I proved that this was true for $n = 0$, and to show that it would work everywhere (what we call heredity in french) I tried to prove that $U_{k+1} = (2/5)Uk + 3 = 3(2/5)_{k+1} + 5$

Comment: Sorry I meant $U_{k+1} = (2/5)U_{k} + 3 = 3(2/5)^{k+1) + 5$ at the end of my last comment.

Comment: @TrevörAnneDenise, it is a "dash" (-) before my name, there is dash before a name in all the comments.  What you have written next appears to be Induction problem, so pls post another question for that so that you get needed explanation

Comment: You are welcome :)